# Debugging javascript TypeError in heavily used function, when console trace doesn't indicate full trace

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox, typeerror

I have a utility function that I use 93 times, let's call it `function add(a,b){return a + b}`

I am getting a `TypeError: a is undefined` in the console at the moment.

Usually when something similar happens, Firefox provides a trace of the line numbers of the code that calls `add` below the error message, allowing me to get back to the cause. However, this time there is no further information.

I've considered adding a break point in the `add` function, however because it gets called so much, it is impractical.

**How should one trace the source of a TypeError in a heavily used javascript function?**

Edit:

As pointed out by Jonas Wilms, the simplifed example will not produce a TypeError. Consider this instead:

```
function add(a,b){
    if (typeof a != 'string'){
        throw Error('my TypeError')
    }
return a + b
}
```

Edit:

I solved this by doing `ctrl-F` on `add(` and stepping through each call until I spotted where undefined inputs were. I still have a feeling there's a better way! Or perhaps a way to arrange code so that this doesn't happen.

Comment: That function will never produce this error.

Comment: @JonasWilms fair point! I attempted to simplify it for the question, I'll see if I can find and alternative

Comment: Okay, so in your alternative "However, this time there is no further information." is no longer true.

Comment: @JonasWilms Now it the error says: `uncaught exception: my TypeError` with no extra information, so same debugging problem.

Comment: Ah right. Always throw `Error`s!

Comment: @JonasWilms thanks! updated the question.